# How can I pass a vector to a function?

Tags: c++

So, what I want to do here is to pass a vector to a function without creating the vector before I call the function. It is just a simplified model of what I am actually up for, so this might seem a little unnecessary, but bear with me :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void function(vector<int> intVector)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < intVector.size(); i++)
    cout << intVector[i] << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    function(vector<int> = {10,12,13});   //does not work :(
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This code does not compile

```
function(vector<int> = {10,12,13});
```

and I am wondering what I need to do to get it working. Thank you!

ADDED:
The problem is that I am trying to pass my vector to the parent class' constructor in the initializer list of child constructor and making a copy of vector just to pass it later is troublesome.

Comment: what is vector<int> = {10,12,13}?

Comment: It is my bad attempt to create a vector in the function call and pass it right away to that function.

Comment: If you know how to pass an **int** object to `void function(int)`, you should, of course, know how to pass a **vector<int>** object to `void function(vector<int>)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `function` like this:

```
function({10,12,13});
```

This will use the `std::initializer_list` constructor of `vector` to construct the argument. Notice that you accept a `vector` by value, which could result in a copy. You might want to use:

```
void function(const std::vector<int>& v) {}
```

as your signature if you don't modify the argument.

If your compiler does not support the `initializer_list` feature (Visual Studio or a missing `-std=c++11` switch on `clang`/`gcc`) you will need to create a temporary and initialize it manually.

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(10); v.push_back(12); v.push_back(13);
function(v);
```

Comment: Isn't `vector(initialize_list)` constructor explicit?

Comment: As advised, I called function({10,12,13}) , but it does not work :( It says: expected primary-expression before '{' token
@pmr

Comment: I guess `std::initializer_list` is a C++11 feature. Make sure your compiler supports it. Visual Studio for example only supports it since VS2013.

Comment: @user3496846 Ah, so you need to create a temporary on the stack. I assumed you knew what the `{...}` syntax is and just got confused about using it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
// Create vector
std::vector<int> vi{ 10, 12, 13};

// Pass vector to function
function( vi );

// Receive vector parameter at function

  // Option 1: If you want to modify the passed vector
  void function( std::vector<int> & vp );

  // Option 2: if you do not want to modify the passed vector
  void function( std::vector<int> const & vp );
```

Comment: @arun The problem is that I am trying to pass my vector to the parent class' constructor in the initializer list of child constructor and making a copy of vector just to pass it later is troublesome.

Comment: @user3496846: It would help if you can include the relevant code of parent and child in your question. Without that it is kind of hard to understand your program structure and the specific problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said:

1/ Use `function(const std::vector<int>& intVector)` as the function signature.

2/ Call it with `function( {10,12,13} );` from main().

3/ Compile with std::initializer_list support enabled: `g++ -std=c++0x filename.C`

Give that a go.